# Azure Pipeline Task never finishes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure Pipeline Task never finishes because is waiting for a response from other remote machine in AWS that has a Firewall which cuts connections every 5 mins maximum.

How can I configure a keep alive or something similar to keep the connection alive between both servers (self-hosted and the remote AWS) while the task recieves the remote response.

Answer (score 0):

It was not stated how you setup a connection between your pipeline agent and your AWS remote machine or how the AWS firewall was configured to cut the connection every 5 minutes.

If possible, you may consider configuring the AWS remote machine as a self-hosted agent directly. For my example, I setup self-hosted agent on my AWS EC2 instance. Since the it was installed as a service on the machine listening to the job requests from Azure DevOps, the connection between the agent service on my remote machine and Azure DevOps was restricted by my AWS security group outbound rules. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4) to help configure the firewall of the AWS self-hosted agent machine.

[image]